# Oracles CTXCAT index and diacritice

Tags: oracle

is it possible to get the following condition return true using the CTXCAT index ?

```
pát = pat
```

I've created the index using the minimal configuration

```
CREATE INDEX indexname ON table(column) INDEXTYPE IS CTXCAT;
```

and the it's not picking up the word `pát`

```
 where catsearch(Name,'pát',null) >0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this before making the index?

```
begin
  ctx_ddl.create_preference ('MY_LEX','BASIC_LEXER');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute ('MY_LEX','BASE_LETTER','YES');
end;
/
```

Create the index

```
CREATE INDEX My_Index ON MyTable (my_column)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT
PARAMETERS ('Lexer MY_LEX
             ...
             ')
```

PS: Add at least the Oracle version you are working with

Comment: We're using oracle 10 and 11. Could you please explain little bit what have you done there ?

Comment: Search the Oracle documentation for Lexer. You can configure Oracle Text quite a lot